# Google drive api doesn't show correct quota usage for gmail

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use google drive api to fetch quota used for gmail. The response that I get from the api is below:
api used: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

```
{
 "quotaBytesTotal": "246960619520",         //246.96061952 GB
 "quotaBytesUsed": "5256850",
 "quotaBytesUsedAggregate": "85358344030",        //85.35834403 GB
 "quotaBytesUsedInTrash": "0",
 "quotaType": "LIMITED",
 "quotaBytesByService": [
{
 "serviceName": "DRIVE",
 "bytesUsed": "0"
},
{
 "serviceName": "GMAIL",
 "bytesUsed": "85353087180"       //85.3531 GB
},
{
 "serviceName": "PHOTOS",
 "bytesUsed": "0"
}
```

Where as when I login to my gmail account I see below information:

```
34% full
Using 79.59 GB of your 230 GB
```

Which doesn't seem to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of binary/decimal confusion when calculating capacity. You're converting 'bytes' to 'gigabytes' by dividing by a decimal 'billion' (10^9). But think like a computer: you really want to be be dividing by 2^30 (1024*1024*1024).

246960619520 / 10^9 = 246.9 GB

246960619520 / 2^30 = 230.0 GB

See also: [Binary vs. Decimal Measurements](http://www.dewassoc.com/kbase/hard_drives/binary_v_decimal_measurement.htm)